# Use of the element iframe in xhtml 1.1

Tags: iframe

Please, I am not a programmer, all I want to do is use iframes on my wordpress blog which is validating as xhtml 1.1.

If I use the iframe I am not validating. I get the error element "iframe" undefined

Amazon.com, widgets and astore links all come as framesets or iframes. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Just an FYI, I just checked http://www.amazon.com with http://validator.w3.org/ and they get 100+ errors. (Or something like that...)

Answer (score 1):

The `iframe` element is not part of [XHTML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/doctype.html#s_doctype). Either Amazon etc. are using a different doctype, or their web pages would not validate. I guess those are basically your choices.

*EDIT*: actually, there is some talk in the specification about [customizing XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_dtd.html#a_xhtml11_customization). I'm not familiar with this sort of thing but perhaps you could look into whether it would allow you to modify the DTD to include the `iframe` element.

Comment: David, thank you very much for that response, BUT, going to the link provided was of no use to me, only because nothing made sense to me. 

I am a 64 year old lay person, and just want to know how to use an iframe on my blog and have it validated as an xhtml 1.1 document at the same time. 

I ask this because I have visited blogs that use the very same Amazon.com links and they are validated for xhtml 1.1.  

I am using the iframes with no problem, BUT I would also like to be validated. The iframe is the only error that is preventing my blog from being validated.

Comment: @Noel Benjamin DCosta: I understand your situation of not having the background knowledge to understand the XHTML specification. But that sort of situation is a frequent occurrence for those of us who do programming or web development, and it falls on us to do whatever research is necessary to understand the document. Would you rather I just tell you that it's impossible? Because honestly, that is the answer. The `iframe` element is not valid XHTML 1.1. (If you edit your question to include a link to one of these blogs that apparently uses it, maybe we could tell you what's going on.)